# Why can't I load external scripts from outside servers while Modernizr.load can?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, modernizr

I keep having this doubt in my mind, I want to test if an URL exists before loading the script from that URL, but the way I'm trying to do it fails, as I'm using XMLHTTPRequests and as many know, when you use this method to GET a file from a server that it's not the same as the script that executes the GET, you will get back `is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` .

So how come `Modernizr.load()` method can theoretically load the scripts and I cannot even see if there's actually something there ?

Comment: can load scripts from any site... think CDN?? Can't make ajax request though to test url for the same

Comment: @charlietfl ~ I'm sorry but I'm not following ...

Comment: https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/blob/master/yepnope.js

Comment: I have just read through the source code and I realized that they insert script tags ... so that's not making any XMLHTTPRequests ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Modernizr.load()`, like @dm03514 mentions, loads the script not through XMLHttpRequest, but by inserting a `<script` tag **which doesn't have the cross-domain restriction**. It then tries to check if the script loaded correctly, but that's not an easy task and it may not be possible in all browsers. For more detail you can see this recopilation of the support of different browsers for the various options available for checking success of loading scripts/css: http://pieisgood.org/test/script-link-events/

As for why XMLHttpRequest fails, you can read more about cross-domain restrictions at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control

Some motivations for using script loaders are:

1. Loading scripts based on conditions like what yepnope and YUI do
2. Load scripts asynchronously for performance reasons ( tags block the rendering of the page).
3. Dependency injection (load resources that other scripts need, this is what requirejs does)
4. Load scripts when certain events happen (load hew functionality when a user clicks on a tab)

Also when you use script loaders, you usually load everything from them, including your application code, so that your application code has access to all dependencies. The require.js model (google AMD modules) is a great way of organizing your app. It allows you to write small modules that do specific tasks and reuse them, instead of one big file that does everything.

Comment: Yes, I have just seen that in the source code ... and I believe that Require.js works the same way ...

Comment: but then ... what's the point in using such loaders ? of course besides the benefit of using Modernizr's testing capabilities ?

Comment: There are many reasons. Off the top of my head I can think of:
1) Loading scripts based on conditions like what yepnope and YUI do 2) load script asynchronously for performance reasons (<script> tags block the rendering of the page) 3) dependency injection (load resources that other scripts need, this is what requirejs does) 4) load scripts when certain events happen (load hew functionality when a user clicks on a tab)

Comment: so what you're saying that injecting script tags is better than having the tag at the bottom of the page ? well .... that makes sense but is it really worth it having a script that does all of this which might take a while to do what it does while just having the plain script tag in the HTMl at the risk that it may slow down the page loading time ? I mean you will still not be able to use the JS functionality until the JS or the script is loaded either way .... as for the rest of your arguments ... i totally agree to load certain chunks of code only when needed ...

Comment: Putting the scripts at the bottom will allow the content of the page to be rendered faster, but using asynchronous scripts will also fire the DOMReady event faster. I edited the answer with more ideas about AMD modules

Comment: thanks ... I appreciate the effort (: I will have something to read about tonight (: